Speed optimization of pyshark
Is there a way to speed up pyshark processing?
Details
The rate in which pyshark loops over the packets is ~1000 packet per second, is it possible to speed it up?
For comparison, scapy was checked which provided triple the speed but still not fast enough for many large files (note: calling tshark directly was checked for the same file, which finished in less than a second).
Analysis
Following code was used to capture the rate using pyshark
import pyshark
import time

def analyze_packet_rate(pcap_file):
    cap = pyshark.FileCapture(pcap_file)
    
    sub_start = start = time.time()
    count = 0
    print("Start reading packets")

    for packet in cap:
        count += 1
        if count % 2000 == 0:
            current = time.time()
            elapsed_time = current - sub_start
            print(f"- Packet read rate is {2000 / elapsed_time:.1f} packets per second")
            sub_start = current

    end = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end - start
    print(f"- Took {elapsed_time:.4f} seconds to loop over the {count} captures")

    cap.close()

pcap_file = '/path/to/file.pcap'
analyze_packet_rate(pcap_file)

And following was also used to profile scapy
from scapy.all import PcapReader
import time

def analyze_packet_rate_scapy(pcap_file):
    with PcapReader(pcap_file) as packets:
        sub_start = start = time.time()
        count = 0
        print("Start reading packets")

        for packet in packets:
            count += 1
            if count % 2000 == 0:
                current = time.time()
                elapsed_time = current - sub_start
                print(f"- Packet read rate is {2000 / elapsed_time:.1f} packets per second")
                sub_start = current

        end = time.time()
        total_time = end - start
        print(f"- Took {total_time:.4f} seconds to loop over the {count} captures")

# Example usage
pcap_file = '/path/to/file.pcap'
analyze_packet_rate_scapy(pcap_file)

And following are the results, respectively
# Using pyshark
Start reading packets
- Packet read rate is 1031.2 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 777.1 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 880.9 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 976.2 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 994.7 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 934.5 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 989.5 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 954.8 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 1070.1 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 676.4 packets per second
- Took 23.4697 seconds to loop over the 21431 captures

# Using scapy
Start reading packets
- Packet read rate is 4202.5 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 3486.7 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 3378.4 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 2901.2 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 3092.6 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 3074.6 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 3111.7 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 3017.1 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 3299.8 packets per second
- Packet read rate is 3277.0 packets per second
- Took 6.6108 seconds to loop over the 21431 captures


Have you tried include_raw=False?

It's by default set to False, I tried to set it to True to check the difference. And it was faster using include_raw=True (which requires either use_json (doubled the speed) or use_ek(tripled the speed)). After the machine was put to sleep and brought back the pyshark avg => 2.5k/s pyshark(use_json) => 5.5k/s pyshark(use_ek) =>  8.7k/s and scapy => 7.4k/s

So the problem isn't yet solved by that? I don't think there's any way better though, it seems how it was designed.

After using use_ek, some adjustments were needed, I also moved into having a full scan first to create an in-memory version of the capture and then utilizing the aggregated list for further processing, and the current speed gain w.r.t. to the current needs would set the issue to be solved. For other readers, if the reached speed is not matching the requirements, I would recommend preprocessing using tshark first then working on the data.

If you mentioned those insights into an answer I would accept it. And thanks for hinting to the include_raw option in the first place ^_^
